How to prevent a 2GP Package from being blocked by a customer's validation rules?
When a user installs my AppExchange package, I am using the InstallHandler to run a Batch job to populate a new custom field on the Opportunity object for every single opportunity, as recommended here.
However, customer validation rules often break the Batch job, and errors like FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION (caused by validation rules) and INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ID (not yet sure what causes this insufficient access error, since I'm running in system mode) are common. The batch job is without sharing, all SOQL is AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE, and all DML is update as system.
Does anyone have any solutions to work around this, without asking every customer to change their validation rules?
My only idea: The only solution I could think of is to create a custom object, OpportunityDetail__c, which holds my custom field, and has a Master-Detail relationship with Opportunity. Then my SOQL queries would be [Select mycustomfield, opportunity.amount, opportunity.leadsource, opportunity.customercustomfield__c, opportunity.account.name, etc... from OpportunityDetail]. I imagine this would stop validation rule errors and hopefully INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ID errors since I never touch the Opportunity object, but it also seems like I might be over-engineering a simple problem. Additionally, I run this query so often, I'm worried the master-detail lookup required from OpportunityDetail to Opportunity in every SOQL query will be significantly slower than just having the custom field on Opportunity.

Fundamentally, you cannot prevent badly written validation rules, or those added after "bad data" exists, from getting in the way. Even trying to use a custom object can fail if you need to ensure there is a direct relationship from the standard object to the custom object (rather than the other way round). And you need to be careful and realize this can add some gotchas around record locking etc. And using a master detail CHILD will definitely make SOQL slower. I do so wish validation rules were only run when one of the fields they reference changes...

Thanks Phil. Ya, I'm surprised that this isn't a more common problem. Adding and populating a custom field seems pretty common.
When you say a custom object can fail if the direct relation goes from standard object to custom object, are you saying if the Standard object is the DETAIL, and the Custom is the MASTER (aka the standard object holds the new relationship id field), then it can fail? I was thinking of doing it the other way, so the custom object is the DETAIL and holds the relation id field, and the Standard object remains untouched.

One other question... are you saying...
[SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM OpportunityHistory) from Opportunity] will run significantly slower, but [SELECT id, opportunity.amount FROM OpportunityHistory] will not run significantly slower than a plain SOQL query? Finally, thank you for pointing out record locking... I hadn't thought of that and will make sure to take it into account.

when adding custom fields to standard objects, you can't ever rely on your postInstall script to work across all orgs if updating that field.  A typical VR one could run into would be `closed won opportunities can't be edited'.  I'd make it the customer's responsibility to manually run your batch job and correct errors (through data fixes or better-tuned Validation rules).   Or, design your package to not enhance standard objects with fields that must be prepopulated

Haha, that is the exact validation rule I hit when running the postinstall batch job on my first customer. I'm also seeing a lot where VRs were created after invalid data existed, and my batch job is bringing that back to the surface. I am experimenting with a custom object 'OpportunityDetail__c' that is Detail to Master Opportunity object. This way, I don't have to touch Opportunity at all, only read it. If it fails, worst case scenario, I'll make it the customers responsibility, but my goal is to make the setup as easy as possible. Thanks for the advice!

Making a custom object the child is the most robust approach, but do remember this requires either doing a sub-select or for you to flip the query to focus on your custom object. You then do need to think about record locks and other aspects. So, yes, isolate your stuff in a separate record can work, at the cost of double storage use (custom object record takes 2K in the DB regardless of number of fields).

If logically your custom field is part of an Opportunity, it belongs in the Opportunity object (makes your customer's reporting life easier). If you can design the app so the field does not require prepopulating - perhaps you can have a batch job that runs with allornothing = false and report on errors to the customer for those objects that can't be populated
